# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in image_style_create_derivative() (line 902 of image/image.module)

Tags: 7, media, cdn

I'm uploading my images to Rackspace cloud CDN using the following code:

```
<?php

if (!empty($entries)) {
  foreach($entries as $value) {

    $container_id = $value['cid'];
    $nid = $value['nid'];
    $id = $value['id'];
    $image_path = $value['image_path'];
    $image_style = $value['image_style'];
    $final_image_name_path = $value['final_image_name_path'];
    $container = $value['container'];
    $users_list = $value['users_list'];
    $api_key = $value['api_key'];
    $regions = $value['regions'];
    $abbreviative = $value['abbreviative'];

    $client = new Rackspace(Rackspace::US_IDENTITY_ENDPOINT, array(
    'username' => $users_list,
    'apiKey'   => $api_key
    ));

    $service = $client->objectStoreService('cloudFiles', $abbreviative);
    $container = $service->getContainer($container);
    $temp_arr = explode("/", $final_image_name_path);
    $end_element = end($temp_arr);

    try {
      $file = $container->getObject($end_element);
      $fileExists = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $fileExists = false;
    }

    if ($image_style == "245") {
      $image_style_w = "168";
    } else {
      $image_style_w = $image_style;
    }

    $style = $image_style_w . "w_" . $image_style . "h";
    $display_style[$image_style] = image_style_load($style);
    $image_destination = str_replace("rcf:///", "public:///rackspace/", $final_image_name_path);
    image_style_create_derivative($display_style[$image_style], $image_path, $image_destination); // Error is expected here!

    if ($fileExists) {
      $file->setContent(fopen('sites/default/files/rackspace/' . $end_element, 'r+'));
      $file->update();
    } else {
      $container->uploadObject($end_element, fopen('sites/default/files/rackspace/' . $end_element, 'r+'), array());
    }
    drupal_unlink($image_destination);
  }
}
drupal_exit();

?>
```

Where I'm getting errors in my dblog as

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in image_style_create_derivative() (line 902 of /image/image.module).`

When I tried to check the code there in the `image.module` its something like this,

```
foreach ($style['effects'] as $effect) {
  image_effect_apply($image, $effect);
}
```

Where might I've been wrong in my custom code?

When I've `print_r($display_style[$image_style])` this is what I've got.

```
Array
(
    [isid] => 1
    [name] => 800w_800h
    [module] => 
    [storage] => 1
    [effects] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Resize
                    [help] => Resizing will make images an exact set of dimensions. This may cause images to be stretched or shrunk disproportionately.
                    [effect callback] => image_resize_effect
                    [dimensions callback] => image_resize_dimensions
                    [form callback] => image_resize_form
                    [summary theme] => image_resize_summary
                    [module] => image
                    [name] => image_resize
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [width] => 800
                            [height] => 800
                        )

                    [ieid] => 1
                    [isid] => 1
                    [weight] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You need to debug what `image_style_load($style)` returns. It doesn't seem to be what you expect. Maybe you're concatenating the image style name incorrectly?

Comment: @Clive, please check I have updated the result of `image_style_load($style)` in my question. Let me know if you can get something there!

Comment: The only way you can get that error is if the `styles` key is missing from the first argument you're passing to `image_style_create_derivative()`. Using the code in the question, assuming your output is correct, it would be impossible to get that error. There's something missing...